# How to use findall function to find all NON alpha numeric characters

Tags: python-3.x

Need to find all non alpha numeric characters in string (called `lorem_ipsum`) and assign the outcome to a variable, `results`.

So would I put:

```
results = lorem_ipsum.findall()
```

?

And if so, what goes in the parentheses?

Comment: `lorem_ipsum.findall(r'\W+')`

Comment: Thank you for replying to me.

So when I input that, I get the error: 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'findall'

Do you know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways to use ***findall*** with regular expressions.

If you want to use it as a ***method***, the leading expression has to be a compiled regular expression object, not a string. The syntax is:

```
regex.findall(string[, pos[, endpos ]])
```

If you want to use it as a ***function***, the syntax is:

```
re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
```